# How do I return a FactoryGirl definition in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rails-console

I have a :quote factory defined in FactoryGirl and would like to view that object in Rails console.

```
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

returns

```
FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError: Factory already registered: quote
from /User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/factory_girl-4.8.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
[8] pry(main)>
```

Unsure of how to 'engage' with this object in console, can you advise please.

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: For learning purposes just look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For learning purposes just look at it!

Huh? It's in the code. Open corresponding file and look at it, to learn what it's doing. As for actual runtime ruby objects - under normal circumstances you **never** have to deal with factory instances directly.

But your curiosity will not go unsatisfied. Loaded factories go to `FactoryGirl.factories`. Inspect away. :)

Comment: aha, yes indeed a little pointless, but just trying to look and learn at the actual object. Thanks Sergio.